# Which android.api Should i use in Buildozer for My Kivy APP?

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I have a Kivy APP and before i used android.api 31 and android.api 32 in buildozer init.
There is no problem.
Today i tried android.api 33 and I created an aab file and signed it.
When i sent it as a new release to update, i got en error in Ggoogle Play Console.

**1 Error**

```
Your app targets Android 13 (API 33) or above. You must declare the use of advertising ID in Play Console.

Complete Declaration
```

**And the Declaration:**

```
Does your app use advertising ID?
This includes any SDKs that your app imports that use advertising ID


No

Yes

When you answer this question, make sure to verify if any third-party SDK code in your app uses advertising ID. If so, you must declare that your app uses it. Some SDKs, such as the Google Mobile Ads SDK (Play Services-ads) may already declare the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission in the SDK's library manifest. If your app uses these SDKs as dependencies, the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission from the SDK's library manifest will be merged with your app's main manifest by default, even if you don't explicitly declare the permission in your app's main manifest. Learn more
```

**My Questions are:**

1. I have no ad and i coded my app it in Python, If i use android.api 33 aab file what should be the answer for Declaration. I think it should be NO, am i right? One day if i use Admob in any other app answer should be Yes?
2. If i use android.api 33, does the app work only on Android 13?
   Can it work on Android 5.0? android.api 33 means up to Android 13 ot only Android 13?
3. if android.api 33 does not support below 13 Android versions Beside android.api 33 which mone sould i use android.api 32 or android.api 31

Thanks very much.
Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

1. Although you do not have ads in your app, some 3rd party library (e.g. Google Analytics) might include an advertising ID. If your app directly, or any library you use in your app uses advertising ID you need to answer `yes`, otherwise you can select `no`
2. `minSdkVersion` defines the minimum Android version your app will run on. `targetSdkVersion` is mainly to tell that the app has been tested on a specifc Android version, and you can use newer features of Android in your app (if they are available on the device the app runs on)
3. If you need to support lower sdk versions than 33 for your app, you need to define `minSdkVersion` in you apps `build.gradle` file, which can be lower than your `targetSdkVersion`